# Can't iterate or find length of complex Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a complex Javascript array which when written to the console looks like this :

```
function Standing(flagsmall, teamname, won, drawn, lost, goalsfor, goalsagainst, points) {
        this.flagSmall = flagsmall;
        this.teamName = teamname;
        this.won = won;
        this.drawn = drawn;
        this.lost = lost;
        this.goalsFor = goalsfor;
        this.goalsAgainst = goalsagainst;
        this.points = points;
    }

 var arrStandings = new Array();

serviceUrl = "http://cloudapp.net/odata/Standings?$expand=Team,Stage&$filter=Team/Group/GroupName eq 'A'";
        var line = "";

        $.getJSON(serviceUrl, function (results) {

            $.each(results['value'], function (i, item) {

                //calculate points
                var points = (item.Won * 3) + (item.Drawn * 1);

                var standing = new Standing(item.Team.FlagSmall, item.Team.TeamName, item.Won, item.Drawn, item.Lost, item.GoalsFor, item.GoalsAgainst, points);

                arrStandings.push(standing);
                arrStandings.sort(sortfunction);
            });
        });
```

[image]

Yet when I try to iterate through it I cannot and when I check it's length it returns 0 :

```
console.dir(arrStandings.length);

    arrStandings.forEach(function (index) {

        ...
    });
```

How do I access the objects within the array?

Comment: We'll need more information about how this _Array_ is created than just `new Array`

Comment: very strange - You're not telling us the code: Your console-screen have the information that the length of the array is `4`.

Comment: Please see how the array was created in the edit above

Comment: are you sure your getting the data from Json file - added success: call back and see what you get and an error:

Comment: `GET http://cloudapp.net/odata/Standings?$expand=Team,Stage&$filter=Team/Group/GroupName%20eq%20%27A%27 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED `

Comment: I removed the actual name of the cloudapp, but it does return the data shown in the screenshot

Comment: $.getJSON is an asynchronous operation, when you're writing the length to the console it has not yet been populated.  The representation displayed in the javascript console is rendered after the array is created, when it is first accessed.

Comment: @JonathanMiles You should write that as an answer

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LGJ5R/

Comment: As Jonathan said, `$.getJSON` is **ajax** and the **a** in **ajax** stands for **asynchronous**. This means that you need to wait for the callback to complete first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a 100% clear from your code but looks like you are trying to print the length of the array before it has been populated.

$.getJSON is an asynchronous operation, so at the point in time when you're writing to the console it has not yet been populated.

The representation displayed in the javascript console is rendered after the array is created, when it is first accessed.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for, fixed with a done() added to the end of the getJSON

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when i initilized an array but i put a string key, the array was casted to Object. Return this code lenght of your array/object?

```
Object.keys(myArray).length
```

You can iterate the object using for statement:

```
for ( index in arrStanding ){
    // your code
}
```

EDIT:

```
//  here you have an array
arrStandings.push(standing);
// ...and after this line?
arrStandings.sort(sortfunction);
```

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: its the same like each in jQuery.